# How to have independent database values for different users in a Firebase web app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

A backend newbie here. I am setting up a Firebase database for a web project that I am working on. The structure is:

```
'rootNode': {'text': 'string'}
```

There's url1 which opens a webpage that contains several buttons. Each button updates the value of `text` node to a different value:

`firebase.database().ref('text').set('pattern1');`

There's url2 which opens a different webpage that runs some patterns based on `text` value from url1:

`var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('text');`

Since there's only 1 value that governs the patterns in url2, multiple users can't use my app at the same time. If 1 user runs `pattern3`, all others also see pattern3. How to combat that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple users in your app, you must first be able to identify each user. This is done with [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start). In its simplest for you can use [Firebase's anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#authenticate-with-firebase-anonymously) to simply create a unique ID for each browser instance that opens your web app with:

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
```

After adding the above, you can detect when the user signs in or out with this code:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
    var uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
    // ...
  }
  // ...
});
```

The `uid` in the above code is the unique ID that Firebase Authentication generates for you. Now you can use this UID to give each user their own set of values in the database. For example if you change the code to:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    var uid = user.uid;
    firebase.database().ref('users').child(uid).set({ text: 'pattern1' });
  }
});
```

And if you run this for a few users/browser instances, you'll get a structure like this:

```
{
  "users": {
    "uidOfUser1": {
      "text": "My first text"
    },
    "uidOfUser2": {
      "text": "Hello world"
    },
    "uidOfUser3": {
      "text": "I am here"
    }
  }
}
```

To then elsewhere in your code read the data for the current user, you'd do:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    var uid = user.uid;
    firebase.database().ref('users').child(uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val().text);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.